# External Js is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image: Please click here to see Structure of my project]

Trying to include map from http://www.vincentbroute.fr/mapael/  in my tenant.php

Using :

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.mapael.js" type="text/javascript" >  </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.mapael.js" />

<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/world_countries.js" type="text/javascript" >  </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>js/world_countries.js" />
```

Please help . I am new to codeigniter but i worked on php . Please help in detail that where should i keep my js file and code in detail .

Comment: Your main application folder is where the actual public html folder is? Or it is the CI's application folder?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new folder on your root folder(where the application and system folders are there) and call it `assets`. Put `js` folder inside of it. Then, you can use this structure:

```
<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/jquery.mapael.js');?>" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/world_countries.js');?>" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```